# JavaScript : get decimal separator used in input type="number"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to consistently display decimal numbers in an AngularJS app.

Decimal numbers in the text (span/div/...) should be displayed with the same separator as decimal numbers in input fields.

It doesn't matter if commas or dots are used.

How to find the decimal separator that the browser uses in 
`<input type="number">` fields?

I tried using `toLocaleString` and AngularJS's `number filter`, but this does not always match with input fields, as some browsers do not take the user's locale into account for input fields.

I don't want to use `<input type="text">`,  for usability reasons on mobile devices.

Comment: *"...as some browsers do not take the user's locale into account for input fields."* Really? Blech.

Comment: If it's really the case that browsers are using the wrong thousands/decimal separators in `input type="number"` fields (which is hard to believe, frankly, but I don't have time now to check), I would say that's not your problem: File bug reports with the relevant browser vendors, use the correct, locale-specific one (e.g., `toLocaleString` or Angular's `number` formatter), and if anyone complains about the inputs, direct them at the bug reports.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the problem is that the HTML5 spec doesn't say much about this. Browsers are pretty free to display input fields as they wish, and not all of them use locale. See for example this blog: https://ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization

Comment: Regarding `<input type="number">` only allows number, not dots or commas or any type of formatters

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the number filter? It uses the current locale to decide the number format.

```
<span>{{val | number:2}}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: But as the OP said: *"...as some browsers do not take the user's locale into account for input fields"* If this uses the locale, like `toLocaleStting` does, it has the same problem, no?